# gnuplot - math symbols and formulas in .eps

Tags: gnuplot

I am preparing a set of graphs in gnuplot and I am using the following terminal mode:

```
set terminal postscript eps size 8.5cm, 7cm dashed dashlength 3.0 enhanced color font 'Helvetica,10'
```

In these graphs I have some mathematical symbols or formulas which should appear on the labels or x/ytics. The only format I can submit is ".eps" but it seems that  gnuplot can have mathematical formulas in latex teminal mode and ".tex" format. I could not find a way to convert .tex to .eps.

Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Comment: You're already asking the same thing in your previous question. One minute of Googleing takes you to the solution. Run latex on your tex file, then convert the dvi output to eps: `dvips -E -o out.eps out.dvi`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the `epslatex` terminal. A simple example would be:

```
set terminal epslatex size 8.5cm,7cm dashed dashlength color colortext standalone
set output 'mytest.tex'

set xlabel '$\alpha\beta\gamma$'
plot 1/x title '$\frac{1}{x}$'
set output
```

Now you have a complete TeX-file which you can compile as usual:

```
latex mytest.tex
dvips mytest.dvi
ps2eps mytest.ps
```